# How to connect to amazon aws database using given host and port

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a host, login, password and port. However, when I try to folow the host link, it fails. Tried to search for some guides, but there seems to be more information about creating your own databases rather then using someone else's.

What should I do with that data I have to access a database?

Comment: This needs clarification. Is this a host on an EC2 instance? ... or is it an RDS database?

Comment: @macetw Looks like it's rds

Comment: Follow the link in my answer you will get all the details about security group and everything

Comment: My answer was based on you bring a db admin. If that's not true, we'd need more information for what you need to do with the database, using a tool or a programming language API. (which language, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect to RDS by clicking on the host link it. You have to use a client like MYSQL Workbench to connect to the DB.

Follow this steps in this link

http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/10/amazon-aws/remotely-connect-to-an-aws-rds-instance-using-mysql-workbench

You can also use Command line search for it.

If you have postgres RDS you have to use client like pgadmin check this link.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html

Comment: Is it OK to use this one? (I think my database is Postgres) https://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: Check edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Presuming this is on an EC2 instance...

Ensure your security group grants incoming access on that port from the ip address.

Ensure that ec2 instance had a publicly accessible IP address.

Ensure you can run a datasheet client on that EC2 instance itself. (MySQL client for example)

Even if we're talking about an RDS endpoint, you still need to double check your security group.  Also, ensure that your firewall on your end isn't blocking the access.

Comment: What is a security group? Do I need to sign up in aws.amazon.com or is it possible to access the database using the login/pass I was given? Is it correct to just use "host:port" as an URL in browser?

Comment: Usually you'll set up the connection string with the host:port as the Server parameter.  However, that's only one side of the coin, the server itself needs to be configured to allow incoming connections on that port (and configured to know what to do with it as well).